# Why does the W3C validator say there was an error in this code?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

The error is:

> No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.

And according to the [W3C validator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Markup_Validation_Service) the error is caused by this part:

```
<p>
    <a href="">Anasayfa</a> » <a title="Emlak Bul" href="Emlak-Bul">Emlak Bul</a> » <a title="Mersin Emlak İlanları" href="ilan/siralama/Mersin-Emlak-İlanları">Mersin</a> » <a title="Mersin Satılık Emlak İlanları" href="ilan/siralama/Mersin-Satılık-Emlak-İlanları">Satılık</a> » <a title="Mersin Satılık Ev Konut" href="ilan/siralama/Mersin-Satılık-Ev-Konut">Ev Konut</a> » Yazlık
    <div id="kategori_degistir">
        <p>
            Aramanızı Daraltın
        </p>
        <p>
            İlçe : <a title="Mersin Erdemli Satılık Yazlık" href="ilan/siralama/Mersin-Erdemli-Satılık-Yazlık">Erdemli</a>, <a title="Mersin Mezitli Satılık Yazlık" href="ilan/siralama/Mersin-Mezitli-Satılık-Yazlık">Mezitli</a>
        </p>
        <p>
            Özellik : <a title="Mersin Satılık Yazlık 1+1" href="ilan/siralama/Mersin-Satılık-Yazlık-1+1">1+1</a>, <a title="Mersin Satılık Yazlık 2+1" href="ilan/siralama/Mersin-Satılık-Yazlık-2+1">2+1</a>, <a title="Mersin Satılık Yazlık 3+1" href="ilan/siralama/Mersin-Satılık-Yazlık-3+1">3+1</a>, <a title="Mersin Satılık Yazlık 4+1" href="ilan/siralama/Mersin-Satılık-Yazlık-4+1">4+1</a>, <a title="Mersin Satılık Yazlık 4+2" href="ilan/siralama/Mersin-Satılık-Yazlık-4+2">4+2</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</p>
```

You can check that error from [this link](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.bedavaemlaksitesi.com/mersinemlakrehberi210/ilan/siralama/Mersin-Sat%25C4%25B1l%25C4%25B1k-Yazl%25C4%25B1k&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.2).

Am I missing something here? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A paragraph cannot contain a div, but the end tag for the paragraph element is optional.

`<p><div>` means the same as `<p></p><div>`

Consequently, when you have your actual `</p>`, the paragraph is **already closed**.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `p` tag to contain `div` and other `p`.

The `p` tag was intended to contain text and other inline elements, NEVER block-level elements. This is why the validator is telling you off.

Answer (score 0):

The `p` tag can contain only "inline" elements and isn't supposed to contain a `div` "block" level element.

Another tiny note is that you're not supposed to have empty anchor tags (`<a href="">`). People usually add an empty hash in there `<a href="#">`

Comment: Paragraph elements are block, they just have a content model that only allows them to contain inline elements.

Comment: The URI '' resolves to the current URI. It is about as sane as `#` which resolves to the top of the current page.